# Spring XD stream or batch job

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-xd

I'm evaluating Spring XD as a replacement for a nightly ETL batch process from Mongo to Netezza (our relational data warehouse).

My process needs to do the following one or more times a day and I expect several million records per day so I must have JDBC batching:

1. get the most recent record in the data warehouse via a simple query (select max(lastUpdateDtm) from xyz')
2. Use that timestamp to fetch all the records from Mongo modified after that date
3. Translate/decompose the mongo documents into several JDBC rows ('SqlParameterSource' objects) and commit them every 10k rows or so
4. Call a stored procedure in Netezza to update a few tracking/history tables.

I see 2 approaches, but both have drawbacks:

1. Use a spring-xd stream (ie: "trigger --cron 1 * * * | mongo | jdbc")

   - jdbc sink is not batch oriented, I can't afford 10+million individual JDBC inserts so I would have to write my own sink probably.
   - not quite sure how to do the initial timestamp lookup query elegantly without having to double define jdbc parameters.  Same for step 4.
2. use a batch job with initial timestamp lookup tasklet and use MongoReader and JdbcBatchWriter then compose a stream like such "trigger --cron 1 * * * > queue:job:myBatchJob"

   - This seems less reusable and potentially more work

Any suggestions or recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since having the batch job would be better fit for your usecase (for chunk oriented processing etc.,), you might want to construct a stream that triggers the batch job (at each step) based on the batch job notification (from the previous step).

To use job notifications, you can refer here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#_retrieve_job_notifications